# Align vertical line in fancyhdr to text block

Tags: fancyhdr

I’m having trouble defining a vertical line as part of my page header using `fancyhdr`.

On left pages the line does not align with the text block.

[image: le]

As it should and as it works fine on the right side.

[image: ro]

What is wrong in my code? (See MWE below.) In addition I would like to change the text on the right side to the title of the chapter instead of the title of the section.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}



\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chaptername\space\thechapter}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{##1}{}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE]{\begin{picture}(0,0)\put(0,0){\thepage\space\vheadline\space\leftmark}\end{picture}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\rightmark\space\begin{picture}(0,0)\put(0,0){\vheadline\space\thepage}\end{picture}}
\voffset-10mm
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\def\vheadline{%
    \begingroup\color{gray}\rule[-1pt]{1pt}{1000pt}\endgroup}


\begin{document}

\title{Simple Book Example}

\mainmatter

\chapter{The First Chapter}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `\makebox[0pt]` to hide the width of the page number and the rule and `\smash` to hide the height and the depth of the rule.

```
\fancyhead[LE]{%
    \makebox[0pt][r]{\thepage\space\smash{\vheadline}}%
    \space\leftmark
}
\fancyhead[RO]{%
    \rightmark\space
    \makebox[0pt][l]{\smash{\vheadline}\space\thepage}%
}
```

If the text of the chapter title should be on odd pages instead the text of the section title change the redefinition of `\chaptermark` and `\sectionmark` to

```
\renewcommand*{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chaptername\space\thechapter}{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\sectionmark}[1]{}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand*{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chaptername\space\thechapter}{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\sectionmark}[1]{}
\fancyhf{}

\fancyhead[LE]{%
    \makebox[0pt][r]{\thepage\space\smash{\vheadline}}%
    \space\leftmark
}
\fancyhead[RO]{%
    \rightmark\space
    \makebox[0pt][l]{\smash{\vheadline}\space\thepage}%
}
\voffset-10mm
\renewcommand*\headrulewidth{0pt}
\newcommand*\vheadline{\textcolor{gray}{\rule[-1pt]{1pt}{1000pt}}}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\title{Simple Book Example}
\mainmatter
\chapter{The First Chapter}
\section{A section}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works great. Thank you!
One thing is missing though. How do I add the title of the chapter instead of the title of the section on right pages? Replacing `\sectionmark` with `\chaptermark` leads to the section title with the section number for some reason?!

Comment: I did not read this second question. Now I have updated my answer.